# Who do go there?-VS- Who go there?

Tags: wh-questions

1. Who do go there? The boys in this school go there. Is it correct form of wh-question?

When should I use "who does go,,,,,", and when " who do go,,,,,"?

Can I ask it(#1) in this way?

Who go there?

Are they all correct sentences?

Answer (score 3):

When asking questions about ***who*** does something, it's usual to use the third person singular form of the verb - so "who **goes** there" or "who **does go** there".

You would usually use the simple form unless you are wanting a contrast.

> "Oh, I don't go there."
>   "Well, who does go there?"

There's a contrast here between the unknown person or people who go there, and the erson who already spoke who doesn't. If it's a question without such a contrast, stick to the simpler:

> "Who goes there?"

Note that this is also a well-known saying used stereotypically by sentries to question someone approaching their guard-post. It's a bit of a cliché in that context, but it's fine in other situations where it's just asking a question, rather than challenging someone.